# Get mobile no or sim serial no in a call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

when we receive a call we can get incoming mobile no by below mentioned code,but If it is a dual sim mobile How do I get my ringing number or sim serial number ?Please provide me any solution for this matter.

public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        strPhoneNumber =intent.getExtras().getString("incoming_number");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`TelephonyManager telMgr  = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);`

`String simLineNumber = telMgr.getLine1Number();`

obviously, you'll need to ask for: 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Comment: thank you for your comment,As I know this method works only for few cell phone but not all phones.we can get sim serial number by telMgr.getSimSerialNumber().But what happen If it is a dual sim android mobile?